# Set value of Textarea after jquery.colorfy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use jquery.colorfy https://github.com/cheunghy/jquery.colorfy to change the key word color in the textarea.

I can set value use `$('#textarea').text("value");` to change my textarea value.

The problem is: After the code `$('#textarea').colorfy("markdown");`, the command: `$('#textarea').text("value");` is dead.

Could someone tell me what happened? Thanks a lot.

Comment: try to interchange them, execute assignment first

Comment: It might be that plugin hides original `textarea` and show other HTML elements. So either you can use plugin API to change text or find in which `span`, `div` or whatever else shown text is really placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#area').colorfy("markdown");
      $('#area').text("value");//will be hidden you can see by inspecting the html
      $('.area').html("value");// will be visible to you
    });
```

[image: see the image attached]
Note: What i see from the example is it sets **display:none** to the textarea but `creates a div with the same class which is the class of text area` and applies it's own css on these.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#area').colorfy("markdown");
         $("#click").click(function(){
           $('.area').html("value");// will be visible to you
             });
    });
```

```css
.area {
       float: auto;
       margin-left: auto;
       margin-right: auto;
       width: 200px;
       max-width: 200px;
       height: 200px;
       border-color: black;
       border-width: 2px;
       border-style: solid;
       padding: 8px;
       font-size: 15px;
       text-align: left;
     }
```

```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cheunghy.github.io/jquery.colorfy/jquery.colorfy.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cheunghy.github.io/jquery.colorfy/jquery.colorfy.markdown.js"></script>
   <textarea id="area" class="area">
    hi
     </textarea>
<button id="click">click!</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. But my goal is changing textarea value after the user clicking the button.

Comment: as per the current example is you are using $('.area').html("any string"); you can use it on any event you  like.

Comment: Oh, it works fine!!! Thank you very much :D
Could you explain what difference between "." and "#"? Thank you.

Comment: $('.area') - class selector          $("#area") - id selector

Comment: @Akki619 for that id textarea is set to display:none by `colorfy` but it does creates a div with same class name i.e. why using class selector.hope you got it and you are right about selector.you can see the dom constructed.

Comment: @SuchitKumar just came back and saw query by jerry abt . and # so just responded. You are right, colorfy doing display none for original div id and creating new div with same as class name and thus we are accessing via class name selector.... righto...

Answer (score 0):

Do operate first on text of `textarea` before applying `colorfy` or else post applying manage with `span` it adds with `class`

After you write `$('#textarea').colorfy("markdown");` it applies color ie. custom css by modifying the `textarea` text by adding `span and class`. Tested this plugin please see the screenshot below.

[image]

**Quick Note:** Please dubug more as per your need.

Comment: Thank you. I got the point. But how can I change the textarea in this situation? My goal is adding a string in the end of textarea when I push the button. Thank you.